# sfdx force:source:push Cannot read property 'getSourcePath' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When executing **force:source:push --forceoverwrite** I was receiving the following error when trying to delete a component locally and push the changes.

> ERROR:  Cannot read property 'getSourcePath' of undefined. sfdx
>   force:source:push --forceoverwrite ended with exit code 1

What could be a possible reason or solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually created an app to test my component. That was preventing **sfdx force:source:push** to delete the component and complete the operation.

The error message is not clear enough in my opinion, so I decided to share this knowledge. If you have created anything manually on your org, that could be the reason why it's failing. Whether it's related to a deletion, you can try to undo your local changes and then you might be able to push your changes, then go to your org and delete the object there. You should receive a more obvious message this time.